# Matlab webread with google translation api

Tags: matlab, google-api

I have the same problem when i called Google translation API, this is my code

```
url = 'https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2'
Options.ContentType ='Josn';
   options.KeyValue='XXXXXX'; 
response = webread(url,options)
`options.KeyName = 'apikey';
```

the following error appeared :

> Error using readContentFromWebService (line 37) The server returned the message: "Forbidden" for URL,  'https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2' (with HTTP response code 403). 
>   Error in webread (line 115) [varargout{1:nargout}] = readContentFromWebService(connection, options);

I filled key value as it is in my console, any one help?

Comment: Did you go through the steps here: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/getting-started, 

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44065795/how-to-use-google-translate-in-matlab/44078215#44078215

Comment: Thank you Jon,yes i did but really i am afraid when created JSON request file , i don't know where i can save it , can you guide me ? other wise  the answer in stackover flow : stackoverflow.com/questions/44065795/, was related with free translation but Google translation API not free.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too familiar. Just save it in the same directory you call it from. Also, You have 'Josn' above. Not sure if your code is right.